# my wordpress custom post is not saving correctly and not displaying in admin menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Hello_Dolly
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Movie Listing Plugin
Plugin URI: This plugin lists Novies
*/

//Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
function zulfi_movie_register_post_type() {

    $singular = 'Movie Listing';
    $plural = 'Movie Listing';
    $slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( $singular ) );
    $labels = array(
        'name'           => $plural,
        'singular_name'     => $singular,
        'add_new'         => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New ' . $singular,
        'edit'           => 'Edit',
        'edit_item'     => 'Edit ' . $singular,
        'new_item'       => 'New ' . $singular,
        'view'           => 'View ' . $singular,
        'view_item'         => 'View ' . $singular,
        'search_term'         => 'Search ' . $plural,
        'parent'           => 'Parent ' . $singular,
        'not_found'         => 'No ' . $plural .' found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No ' . $plural .' in Trash'
        );
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
            'public'              => true,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 4,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-businessman',
            'can_export'          => true,
            'delete_with_user'    => false,
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'query_var'           => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'post',
            'map_meta_cap'        => true,
            // 'capabilities' => array(),
            'rewrite'             => array( 
                'slug' => $slug,
                'with_front' => true,
                'pages' => true,
                'feeds' => true,
            ),
            'supports'            => array( 
                'title', 
                'thumbnail', 

            )
    );
    register_post_type( $slug, $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'zulfi_movie_register_post_type' );
function zulfi_movie_register_taxonomy() {
    $singular = 'Gener';
    $plural = 'Geners';
    $slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( $singular ) );
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => $plural,
        'singular_name'              => $singular,
        'search_items'               => 'Search ' . $plural,
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular ' . $plural,
        'all_items'                  => 'All ' . $plural,
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit ' . $singular,
        'update_item'                => 'Update ' . $singular,
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New ' . $singular,
        'new_item_name'              => 'New ' . $singular . ' Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate ' . $plural . ' with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove ' . $plural,
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used ' . $plural,
        'not_found'                  => 'No ' . $plural . ' found.',
        'menu_name'                  => $plural,
    );
    $args = array(
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_admin_column'     => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => $$slug ),
        );
    register_taxonomy( 'geners', 'movie_listing', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'zulfi_movie_register_taxonomy' );
function zulfi_movie_add_custom_meta() {
    add_meta_box(
      'dwwp_meta',
      'Listing info',
      'zulfi_movie_meta_callback',
      'movie_listing',
      'normal',
      'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'zulfi_movie_add_custom_meta' );
function zulfi_movie_meta_callback($post){
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__),'ml_movie_listings_nonce');

    $ml_stored_meta=get_post_meta($post->ID);
    ?>
    <div class="wrap movie-listing-form">
             <div class="wrap movie-listing-form">
             <label for="movie_id"><?php esc_html_e('Movie ID','ml-domain'); ?></label>
             <input type="text" name="movie_id" id="movie_id" value="<?php if(!empty($ml_stored_meta['movie_id'])) echo     esc_attr($ml_stored_meta['movie_id'][0]); ?>"/>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="mpaa_rating"><?php esc_html_e('Movie Listing ID','ml-domain'); ?></label>
         <select name="mpaa_rating" id="mpaa_rating"> 
         <?php $option_values=array('G','PG','PG-13','R','NR'); 
         foreach($option_values as $key => $value){
        if($value==$ml_stored_meta['mpaa_rating'][0]){
        ?>
        <option selected="selected" ><?php echo $value ?></option>
        <?php   
        }
        else {
        ?>
        <option><?php echo $value ?></option>
        <?php   
        }
         }
         ?>

         </select>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
         <label for="details"><?php esc_html_e('Details','ml-domain'); ?></label>
         <?php $content=get_post_meta($post->ID,'details',true);
         $editior='details';
         $settings=array('textarea_rows'=>'5','media_buttons'=>true);
         wp_editor($content,$editior,$settings);
         ?>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="release_date"><?php esc_html_e('Release date','ml-domain'); ?></label>
                 <input type="date" name="release_date" id="release_date" value="<?php   echo esc_attr($ml_stored_meta['release_date'][0]); ?>"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="director"><?php esc_html_e('director','ml-domain'); ?></label>
                 <input type="text" name="director" id="director" value="<?php if(!empty($ml_stored_meta['director']))  echo     esc_attr($ml_stored_meta['director'][0]); ?>"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="stars"><?php esc_html_e('stars','ml-domain'); ?></label>
                 <input type="text" name="stars" id="stars" value="<?php if(!empty($ml_stored_meta['stars']))  echo     esc_attr($ml_stored_meta['stars'][0]); ?>"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="runtime"><?php esc_html_e('Run time','ml-domain'); ?></label>
                 <input type="text" name="runtime" id="runtime" value="<?php if(!empty($ml_stored_meta['runtime'])) echo     esc_attr($ml_stored_meta['runtime'][0]); ?>"/>
             </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="trailor"><?php esc_html_e('Youtube ','ml-domain'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="trailor" id="trailor" value="<?php if(!empty($ml_stored_meta['trailor'])) echo  esc_attr($ml_stored_meta['trailor'][0]); ?>"/>
             </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'zulfi_movie_save_meta' );
function zulfi_movie_save_meta($post_id){

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave($post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision($post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce=(isset($_POST['ml_movie_listings_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['ml_movie_listings_nonce'],basename(__FILE__)))?'true':'false';
    if($is_autosave || $is_revision || $is_valid_nonce){
        return;
    }
    if($_POST['movie_id'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'move_id',sanitize_text_field($_POST['movie_id']));
        }
        if($_POST['mpaa_rating'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'mpaa_rating',sanitize_text_field($_POST['mpaa_rating']));
        }
        if($_POST['ratings'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'ratings',sanitize_text_field($_POST['ratings']));
        }
        if($_POST['runtime'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'runtime',sanitize_text_field($_POST['runtime']));
        }
        if($_POST['stars'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'stars',sanitize_text_field($_POST['stars']));
        }
        if($_POST['trailor'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'trailor',sanitize_text_field($_POST['trailor']));
        }
        if($_POST['release_date'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'release_date',sanitize_text_field($_POST['release_date']));
        }
        if($_POST['runtime'])
        {
        update_post_meta($post_id,'runtime',sanitize_text_field($_POST['runtime']));
        }

}
```

This is my code and I don't know what is wrong. According to me, everything is right. It is saving but not data in my custom fields is not showing it seems like there is a problem is with zulfi_movie_save_meta function but i dnt know exactly what problem is. My saved data should show in the custom fields.

Comment: I have checked the code and post save is working on wordpress 4.5.3 Twentysixteen. Which WP version you are using?

Comment: i am using wordpress 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function wp_insert_post ( array $postarr, bool $wp_error = false ) to insert post in db, this function also return an error if post in not being saved in db, so you could get what is wrong,

You could check more details about this function here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following lines from your above code.

```
if($is_autosave || $is_revision || $is_valid_nonce){
    return;
}
```

Correct postmeta movie_id and add post meta for director. Then your entire code will work correctly.